# pygameで音楽ファイルを再生できません

Tags: python, mp3, pygame

pygame.mixerでweb上でダウンロードした音楽ファイルを再生できません。

```
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()
sound =pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/Users/syosh/Desktop/pyworks/data/ball_collided.wav")
sound =pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/Users/syosh/Desktop/pyworks/data/coin07.mp3")
```

`ball_collided.wav` も `coin07.mp3` も同じフォルダに保存しているのですが、以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'C:/Users/syosh/Desktop/pyworks/data/coin07.mp3
```

ゲーム音のフリー素材リンク
https://taira-komori.jpn.org/game01.html

Comment: 各ファイルはWindowsのメディアプレイヤー等では正常に再生できていますか？

Comment: coin07.mp3 を WAV形式(PCM s16le)に変換して `sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('coin07.wav')` とすると問題なく読み込む事ができて、`sound.play()` を実行すると正常に再生されます。おそらく、MP3 format に対応していなのではないかと思います(MP3 ライセンスの問題かも知れません)。

Answer (score 1):

[pygame.mixer.Sound](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound)の説明に書いてありました。
サポートしているファイルフォーマットの問題です。
以下の2つ以外は扱えないようです。

> The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV.
>
> サウンドは、OGGオーディオファイルまたは非圧縮WAVからロードできます。

@metropolis さんコメントのようにあらかじめ変換しておくか、あるいはフォーマットをサポートしている何か他のライブラリで読み込んでメモリ上で`.wav`に変換してから`pygame`に渡す等の対処が必要でしょう。

---

補足：

以下の記事によると、Pythonの音楽系で.mp3からフォーマット変換をサポートしているのは pydub + ffmpeg のみで、しかも変換だけではなくファイルへの書き出しが組み合わされるようで、メモリ上での変換だけという機能は無さそうです。
[Playing and Recording Sound in Python](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/)
[Comparison of Audio Libraries](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#comparison-of-audio-libraries)の項を参照

soundfile + [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) の組み合わせも色々と出来るようですが、.mp3はサポートしていないと明記されています。

> I have decided that I will not be adding support for MPEG Layer 3 (commonly known as MP3) due to the patent issues surrounding this file format. See the FAQ for more.

一応以下のように pydub + ffmpeg  と numpy を組み合わせて何とかするという手もあるようですが、面倒でしょうし。
[【Python/pydub】mp3、wavのデータをNumPy配列に変換](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/pydub-numpy/)
[NumpyのarrayからPydubのAudioSegmentを作成する](https://own-search-and-study.xyz/2017/11/19/numpy%E3%81%AEarray%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89pydub%E3%81%AEaudiosegment%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

ただ、追加でこんなのを見つけたので、使えるかもしれませんね。
[miniaudio](https://pypi.org/project/miniaudio/)

> python bindings for the miniaudio library and its decoders (mp3, flac, ogg vorbis, wav)
>
> miniaudioライブラリとそのデコーダー（mp3、flac、ogg vorbis、wav）のPythonバインディング。

Comment: メモリ上で.wavに変換するというのは単に拡張子を.wavに変えるだけではいけないということでしょうか？

Comment: 拡張子というのはファイル名に付けたヒントであって、実際のデータの中身では無いので、名前を変えただけでは意味がありません。データのフォーマットを変える必要があります。

Comment: web上で変換を行うと読み込むことができました。ありがとうございました。